# SQL Query: Only include PAIRS of rows in query

Tags: sql

Im looking to find pairs of rows in a table like below

MS SQL 2012(maybe 2014)

```
Ref, Split
1, A
1, B
2, B
3, A
3, B
```

Results

```
Ref, Split
1, A
1, B
3, A
3, B
```

pairs of rows are partitioned by 'Ref' ie, 1 and 3 need to be returned, but 2 does not have a pair so should not be returned

I would by default use OVER but i believe this is overkill and not the most effective way of handling this.

What are the alternatives

Comment: Edit your question and provide the database you are using and the sample results.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a self-join and put the results in one row?

```
select t1.ref, t1.split, t2.split
from t t1 join 
     t t2
     on t1.ref = t2.ref;
```

Or if you want the original rows use `exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.ref = t.ref and t2.split <> t.split);
```

Answer (score 0):

If your DBMS supports `count() over()` it's just the way to go.

```
select t.Ref, t.Split
from (
   select Ref, Split, count(distinct Split) over(partition by Ref) cnt
) t
where t.cnt > 1 
-- cnt = 2  if exactly the pairs are required
```

Comment: this is what i would use normally. which is the better option, your answer or the answer by gordon?

Comment: Just try both and look at the execution plan. Query peformance may depend on what indexes exist, etc.